# Brackets in a Where Clause Returns different recordsets

Tags: sql, where-clause, brackets

I have come across a query in my new job and wondered why the previous person would have put brackets around a where clause. There only seems to be one where clause using the between operator.

```
current code being deployed
 Select * from t_Employee where (employee_date between '01 May 2016' and '07 May 2016')

Changed Code
 Select * from t_Employee where employee_date between '01 May 2016' and '07 May 2016'
```

has anyone any idea why would they return different results?
what are the bracket restricting?

Comment: They won't return different results, the are exactly the same. Maybe he thought its more readable, or maybe a program generated this code(there are plenty programs that generates queries with parenthesis on the where clause) . Either way - its the same

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2005 does this affect the syntax of the query?

Comment: I think I was very clear, it does not matter if you use oracle,MySQL, sql-server or any other DBMS.

Comment: Hi Sagi, I thought that but when run, it does return different results, when I run it for a month, some employee's are restricted for today and yesterday? when using the brackets and they are returned for these days when I run it without the query?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting them and they are not just outputting in a different order? Parenthesis can't change anything when there is only one condition

Comment: Yeah, I thought exactly the same but ordered by Employee_Name and Date, for the 17th and 16th not pulled through but only for certain employee's. Am I right in thinking that this points to data anomalies and not query syntax?

Comment: Agree with @sagi, the two SQL statements should generate the same result.

Comment: Yes, as I said, the parenthesis can't change a thing.

Comment: Thanks Sagi, Sorry for drawing it out so much just wanted to make sure my thinking was right.